# Linked List from keyboard input in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing code that takes integers that are input from the user and creates a linked list and then prints out the list. The integers should be put into the front of the list.

I need a little bit of help I don't know how to get the numbers to print out.
Here is my code:

**Node.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _nodes
#define _nodes

typedef struct node_s {
       int d;
       struct node_s *next;
} node1;

node1 list(int d);
node1 addbegin(int d, node1 *head);
node1 print(node1 *head);

#endif
```

**node.c**

```
#include "node.h"
#include <stdio.h>

node1 *list_nodes(int d){
    node1 *node;
    node=(node1*)malloc(sizeof(node1));
    node->d=d;
    node->next=NULL;
    return(node);
}

node1 init(node1 *head){
    head->next=NULL;
}

node1 addbegin_nodes(node1 *head, int d){
    node1 *newnode;
    newnode=(node1*)malloc(sizeof(node1));
    newnode=list_nodes(d);
    head->next=newnode;
    return(newnode);
}

node1 print_nodes(node1 *head){
    node1 *temp;
    temp=(node1*)malloc(sizeof(node1));
    for(temp=head->next;
        temp;
  temp=temp->next)
            printf("%d", temp->d);
    return (d);
}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "node.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    node1 *head;
    node1 *start;
    int num;

    printf("Please enter integers: ");
    while(scanf("%d", &num)!=EOF){
            head=(node1*)malloc(sizeof(node1));
            list(head);
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i>=0;i--){
                    addbegin(head, num);
                    print(head);
            }
            printf("\n");
            print(head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: EOF is a special character. Are you exiting from the loop?

Comment: yes it is a hw question and ive been working on it for like 5 hrs killing myself! so i finally decided to ask for help. EOF is end of file.

Comment: after a call to `addBegin()` the value in `new_node` is your new head, but in your main file you discard it. Try `head = addBegin(...)` ..

Answer (score 0):

Change your print_nodes to

```
//recursive version
void print_nodes(node1 *head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->d);
        print_nodes(head->next);
    }
}
```

Or

```
// normal version
void print_nodes(node1 *head)
{
    node1 *temp = head;

    while (temp != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

I don't now why these methods should return anything, please clarify in comments.

Comment: when i tried that it says node.c:24: warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: line 24 is in your code, i don't know at what in points on my function. It's also warning, not an error. Does the code work
? Did you try both versions?

Answer (score 0):

```
node1 init(node1 *head){
    head->next=NULL;
}
```

Is defined as returning node1, but appears not to have a return statement. Could that be part of your problem?